# how to make smooth nested transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I want to do something like what is in this jsfiddle except I want the max-height of the parent div to be pushed down by the child divs. Right now in order to expand everything fully you need to open up all of the inner divs and then open and close the outer div in order to refresh the max-height. I want the max-height of the parent divs to be pushed out from the child divs. What would be the simplest way to do this?

EDIT: So I know what needs to happen but I don't know how to do it.  I need to use something that measures the maximum height of the parent div when all the divs are not hidden.  This would replace the "content.scrollHeight" variable. I don't know how I am supposed to measure that though.

How would I get the maximum height of the parent div with all the child divs not hidden?

http://jsfiddle.net/yajfwmxq/13/

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("failureHeader");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 class="failureHeader">Div 1</h2>
        <div class="failureContent">
          <h3 class="failureHeader">Div 2</h3>
          <div class="failureContent">
            <h4 class="failureHeader">Div 3</h4>
            <div class="failureContent">
            <p>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Conten</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>

.failureHeader{
  color: #cc0000;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50vw;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.failureHeader:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #cc0000;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 1vw;
}

.failureContent{
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    width: 50vw;
    margin: auto;
}

.failureHeader:hover {
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}
```

Comment: It's tricky because if you read the height while the transition is being executed, it's going to be the _current_ height, not the actual height, which is what you need. A (bad) workaround would be to set a `max-height` bigger than the maximum height expected. Or just use JS for the anumations.

Comment: @Gabriel That's what I did, but I don't like it at all. It messes with my animation and I don't like hardcoding.